# Having Issue on Loading Object to Two Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know why I am not able to load following object `Points` in to 2 dimensional Array `MultiPoints`

```js
 var points = {lat:"48", long:"123"};
    var MultiPoints = [];
    
    for (i = 0; i <3; i++) { 
        MultiPoints.push(points[i].lat, points[i].long );
    }
    
    console.log(MultiPoints);
```

What I need to have is

> var MultiPoints = [
>         [48, 123],   [48, 123],   [48, 123] ];

Comment: Read up on JavaScript objects vs. arrays. Not the same thing.

Comment: lol @Timo that's debatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have an array to iterate, just one object, then you need to push an array as well.

```js
var points = { lat: "48", long: "123" },
    MultiPoints = [],
    i;
    
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    MultiPoints.push([points.lat, points.long]);
}
   
console.log(MultiPoints);
```

A suggestion for mapping multiple points with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> The **`map()`** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var points = [{ lat: "48", long: "123" }, { lat: "49", long: "124" }, { lat: "50", long: "125" }], 
    multiPoints = points.map(function (point) {
        return [point.lat, point.long];
    });
   
console.log(multiPoints);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina specially for the suggestion part!

Comment: i suggest to use a convention for naming variables and use only names with starting upper case letter for classes.